# SimpleXMLElement Object back to XML with greek charachers (UTF-8 encoding)

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

i have an XML which i import with simplexml, then edit and returning it back to a new file.
But the greek characters are being destroyed (escaped?)
How to force it as UTF-8?
Old file has encoding="UTF-8" in xml tag, new file not.

```
$xml=simplexml_load_file("test.xml", 'SimpleXMLElement', LIBXML_NOCDATA);
...
$dom_sxe = dom_import_simplexml($xml);
$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0');
$dom->formatOutput = true;
$dom_sxe = $dom->importNode($dom_sxe, true);
$dom_sxe = $dom->appendChild($dom_sxe);

$dom->save('output.xml');
```

Comment: The `DOMDocument` constructor takes an encoding as second parameter. If that does not solve your issue, then you need to give us some more details.

Comment: Thanks, but how? I can't understand it from documentation at https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.construct.php

Comment: Ok i did it by chance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In 'new DOMDocument', if we add as second parameter the 'UTF-8', it gets it as encoding, and works

```
$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
```